# why Qt signals' arguments can't be defined with typedef types?

Tags: c++, qt, types, signals

For a Qt5/c++11 project, I'm using a QMediaPlayer object (named audio_player) with its positionChanged() signal:

This piece of code is ok:

```
connect(this->audio_player,
        SIGNAL(positionChanged(qint64)),
        this,
        SLOT(audio_position_changed(qint64)));
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
typedef PosInAudio qint64;

connect(this->audio_player,
        SIGNAL(positionChanged(PosInAudio)),
        this,
        SLOT(audio_position_changed(PosInAudio)));
```

At run-time I get the message "QObject::connect: No such signal QMediaPlayer::positionChanged(PosInAudio)"

I was baffled to see that even a type defined with #define wasn't ok:

```
#define PosInAudio qint64

connect(this->audio_player,
        SIGNAL(positionChanged(PosInAudio)),
        this,
        SLOT(audio_position_changed(PosInAudio)));
```

(same error message as above)

Is this the expected behavior ? Or do I make a mistake?

---

As explained above (thank you Matteo Italia), everything's ok if you use the Qt5 new signal-slot syntax described [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that the old-style `connect` actually works comparing *strings* to match the signal and the slot, and here the signature used in the signal declaration ([`void positionChanged(qint64)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#positionChanged)) and the one used in your `connect` call (`void positionChanged(PosInAudio)`) don't match if you are just comparing strings.

The `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are essentially stringifying macros (the actual signature of the old-style `connect` involves `const char *` or equivalent stuff); `connect` performs a normalization on the received strings (removing unnecessary spaces, `const` references & co. - see [`QMetaObject::normalizedSignature`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#normalizedSignature) - but again, with no knowledge of `typedef`s or namespaces) and tries to match them to the signals/slots lists found in the metaobject.

This list, in turn, is generated by the MOC, which has quite a vague understanding of C++ syntax and semantics, and extracts the signal and slots signatures quite brutally; so, neither the strings produced by MOC nor what is put into the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros are aware of subtleties like `typedef`s or "equivalent" names (e.g. a type local to the current namespace, which, when referenced outside, needs to have its name prepended by a namespace), so the `connect` will fail if you have "complicated" (and non-literally matching) type names in your signal and slots.

The new-style (Qt5+) `connect` (mentioned in the comments by *@peppe*) should solve these issues (and permit neat stuff like connecting a signal to a lambda), but if you have to live with old-style `connect`s to avoid problems you should always refer to types in the same way - e.g., if you use a `typedef` in your signal declaration, you have to use it in slots too; if you have namespaced types in the signal, prefix them with the adequate namespaces and do the same in the slots.

Comment: You're being very friendly when you claim that MOC isn't "fully aware" of C++ syntax. There are millions of Java developers who have a better awareness of C++ syntax because of the superficial similarity. MOC is regex-level capable.

Comment: It's not a matter of MOC being "aware", but of old-style connections using string comparisons for determining type equality. That of course breaks with typedefs, but also f.i. with non-fully-qualified (a signal may get declared emitting a local type, such as enum, without qualifying it, and resolution breaks when connecting against a slot which gets the qualified type). **All of these issues are resolved in Qt 5 with the new PMF based connect syntax.**

Comment: AFAICT the new `connect` no longer relies on the MOC step. You can definitely rely on string comparisons to compare two types, that's how mangled names work after all. But those are names mangled by a true C++ compiler.

Comment: @MSalters: `moc` is still necessary. Although now you can connect *to* any member function (not necessarily slots), you must still connect *from* a signal; Qt knows that the passed method is a signal because `moc` extracted that information. (And `moc` still does much more, including building type traits necessary for introspection and cross-thread signals, but that's off topic in this context)

Comment: Doesn't `void positionChanged(PosInAudio);` match `SIGNAL(positionChanged(PosInAudio))`? I don't understand.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: the problem is that the signal [has been declared as `void positionChanged(qint64)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#positionChanged), not `void positionChanged(PosInAudio)`; OP added a `typedef PosInAudio qint64;` and then tried to refer to that signal as `void positionChanged(PosInAudio)`, but the MOC doesn't know a thing about `typedef`s, so it couldn't find the signal.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I expanded a bit the first paragraph (and updated the links while I was at it), I hope it's clearer now (although the new `connect` syntax should make this problem irrelevant nowadays).

Comment: @MatteoItalia does Qt actually document that they do not macro-expand their argument to `SIGNAL` and `SLOT`? Does `moc` take the literally-written or the pre-processed form of the signal declaration, regarding macros?

Comment: In my experience SIGNALS and SLOT stuff isn't much documented, when debugging a similar problem I had to look up their sources (which are brutal stringification, with a prefix "1" for `SLOT` and "2" for `SIGNAL`), as well as those for the MOC. The MOC limitations in turn is a bit more documented, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#limitations); comparing the documentation from 4.8 to 5, I see that the MOC gained some support for expanding macros, but I don't have any direct experience of it (also, I don't understand how that would work, given that `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` don't expand them).

Comment: Still, my personal attitude on this is: don't hope that the MOC or `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` will handle anything more than the very characters you wrote in the source (modulo whitespace) and everything will be fine. Even better, don't rely on old-style `connect` syntax.

Comment: Ok, so I tested some stuff with this [small sample](https://pastebin.com/EBLQEtZx); 4.8 MOC takes everything literally, 5.8 MOC expands the `#define` but not the `typedef`. OTOH, [given how those macros are defined](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h#n276), macros inside them [aren't expanded at all](https://godbolt.org/g/Ycyck1), so I don't think macros inside signals + old-style `connect` can possibly work in Qt 5.

Comment: @MatteoItalia ah I see. I think this is a bug in qt5. If moc expands (for what reason?) but the macros don't.