# Custom type from typedef as Qt MetaType

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple type declared as

```
typedef uint64_t Hash;
```

How can I use this type for the Qt signal/slot structure?

Comment: use qt5 signal/slot syntax

Comment: @user3528438 can't, because my type is not a QMetaType or something like it

Comment: You care declare custom QMetaTypes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/custom-types.html

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I think it should not be needed because this is a simple type

Comment: The problem is solved here. Summery: use new syntax to get around typedef, use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `qRegisterMetaType` to pass custom object through signal/slot, be careful of quirks of namespaces. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119397/emitting-signals-with-custom-types-does-not-work

Comment: As it was written already, you need to declare and register a metatype. You can also find some useful reading here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-tools-customtypesending-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `typedef` is of a fundamental type, there is nothing you have to do to use it for signals and slots (even queued connections work, although those break with the »old« string-based connect syntax).

In my tests (with Qt 5.8) I also didn’t have the issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402685).

If you use an older Qt5 version which still exhibits this, use the new connect syntax (without the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` keywords).